# How to remove a path in pathList if the file in the path already exist

Tags: c#

How to remove a path in pathList if the file in the path already exist?

I got a List path which consist of many string of paths to some files.
What I wonder is that how can I remove a path in the path list if the file is duplciated in another directory path?

For example:

```
/directory/data/testing/testdata.csv
/directory/data/test123/testdata.csv
/directory/data/test123/testdata3.csv?
/directory/data/testing/testdata1.csv?
/directory/data/test123/testdata2.csv?
```

AS you see, both files are identical in another directory, but since I already added the first line to the path list, I want to skip the second like because the file already exist in the path list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: SO is not a platform to do your homework for you. Please update your question and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example and show us in code what you've already tried and where exactly you are stuck. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can GroupBy your list using the Path.GetFileName, then on each group returned by the GroupBy select only the first item in the list

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>
{
    "/directory/data/testing/testdata.csv",
    "/directory/data/test123/testdata.csv",
    "/directory/data/test123/testdata3.csv",
    "/directory/data/otherfolder/testdata3.csv",
    "/directory/data/testing/testdata1.csv",
    "/directory/data/testdata1.csv",
    "/directory/data/test123/testdata2.csv"
    "/directory/data/myfolder/testdata2.csv"
};

paths = paths.GroupBy(p => Path.GetFileName(p))
             .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

foreach(string s in paths)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output is:

```
/directory/data/testing/testdata.csv
/directory/data/test123/testdata3.csv
/directory/data/testing/testdata1.csv
/directory/data/test123/testdata2.csv
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, I don't want to remove the actual file, just excluse the duplicated string in the string list. Like in this case, I want to remove either     "/directory/data/testing/testdata.csv",
 or   "/directory/data/test123/testdata.csv" from my list of string.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I really don't want to lesson you, especially since you have so much more reputation than i do, but providing solutions for such simple issues encourages people to come here and get their code snippets without bringing in any effort.

Comment: I answer the questions that interest me and that help me to understand better some code concepts. Here I have found a way to exercise my understanding of GroupBy and I have choose to answer this question.

Comment: @Steve Thanks a lot! I think it helps, but could you explain the actions and how the groupie and select does in this case? :)

Comment: I'm also curious if it is possible to do this "filter" while you are adding the list? Like if testdata.csv is already in the list, don't add? :) Instead of having to remove afterward. Thanks a lot!

Comment: GroupBy produces an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` similar in a certain way to a Dictionary. In this IGrouping the key is the result of the lambda _Path.GetFileName(p)_ and the value is a list of all the paths with the same key. After that the values from the GroupBy result is passed to Select and this select uses a lambda to extract only the First item in the paths with the same filename

Comment: Sure, you can use _paths.Any(x => Path.GetFilename(x) == Path.GetFileName(valueYouWantToAdd))_ If it returns true then _valueYouWantToAdd_ already exists.

Comment: If you want to exercise these concepts I recommend to install [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and try these examples

Answer (score 0):

Try with next code:

```
//lspath is the list with all paths
        var dataDistinc = lspath.Select(x =>
        {
            //get all files with .csv
            if (Regex.IsMatch(x.Split('/').Last(), ".csv") || Regex.IsMatch(x.Split('/').Last(), ".csv?"))
            {
                var buff = x.Split('/').Last();
                //get the path files with the same files
                var z = lspath.Select(y => { 
                    if(y.Contains(buff)){
                        return y;
                    }
                    return null;
                }).Where(i => i != null).FirstOrDefault();
                //return the first
                return z;
                //return z.Select(j => j != null ? j : null);
            };
            return null;
        }).Distinct();
```